# CouchDb - One design doc with multiple views vs multiple design docs with split views

Tags: couchdb

I am trying to figure out the tradeoffs between these two.

It seems that using one design doc with multiple views is fast to update because when indexing, each doc is passed into each view in a single pass.

But, a tradeoff would be that if I change a view in the design doc, all the views need to be updated.

Does this seem correct? Is there something else someone could add to this understanding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More detail informations can be found [here](http://www.dimagi.com/blog/what-every-developer-should-know-about-couchdb/) :

Views are organized into design docs. Theoretically, you can have as many design docs as you want in a database, and as many views as you want in a single design doc. Theoretically, each view can emit arbitrarily many b-tree nodes per document, and your map/reduce code can be arbitrarily complex. But keep in mind:

- Having many views degrades performance, because each view must be run on every document change
- All views in the same design doc are indexed together; changing, adding, or removing any view requires all of them to be reindexed
- Having many emits per document in a view can degrade performance (but slightly more performant than putting each emit in its own view)
- Complex map and reduce code degrades performance
- Emitting values other than null degrades performance
- Using reduce code other than the _sum, _count, _stats built-ins degrades performance

As a side note CouchDB and Cloudant differ on exactly when views are updated:

- CouchDB updates views lazily, that is when they are queried. This can lead to long wait times for infrequently accessed views.
- Cloudant updates views asynchronously in the background. This means that views that are no longer being accessed are still consuming system resources.

Comment: Another relevant quote from that linked article: "Put every view in its own design document so that each view can be reindexed separately. (Remember, even deleting a view causes a major reindex if it’s in a design doc with other views!)"